# Is it possible to find row by using value of row csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, printing, openpyxl

```
Welcome - Please chose month --November or Oktober--
November
Please choose date numeric. Last date available 16th November
15
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0, 1, 2]
Index: []
                   0    1    2
0   15.11.2021 23:30  165  1,3
1   15.11.2021 23:00  176  1,4
2   15.11.2021 22:30  175  1,6
3   15.11.2021 22:00  173  1,4
4   15.11.2021 21:30  165  1,7
5   15.11.2021 21:00  171  1,7
6   15.11.2021 20:30  176  1,9
7   15.11.2021 20:00  176  1,7
8   15.11.2021 19:30  171  1,8
9   15.11.2021 19:00  167  2,3
10  15.11.2021 18:30  175  1,9
11  15.11.2021 18:00  167  1,9
12  15.11.2021 17:30  169  1,8
13  15.11.2021 17:00  156  2,5
14  15.11.2021 16:30  155  2,4
15  15.11.2021 16:00  156  2,2
16  15.11.2021 15:30  151  2,4
17  15.11.2021 15:00  151    2
18  15.11.2021 14:30  153  2,8
19  15.11.2021 14:00  153  2,9
20  15.11.2021 13:30  152  2,4
21  15.11.2021 13:00  155  2,6
22  15.11.2021 12:30  159  2,2
23  15.11.2021 12:00  168  1,8
24  15.11.2021 11:30  161    2
25  15.11.2021 11:00  166  2,2
26  15.11.2021 10:30  155  1,9
27  15.11.2021 10:00  148  1,7
28  15.11.2021 09:30  152  1,3
29  15.11.2021 09:00  148  1,6
30  15.11.2021 08:30  136  2,9
31  15.11.2021 08:00  131  3,4
32  15.11.2021 07:30  113  2,9
33  15.11.2021 07:00  118  2,7
34  15.11.2021 06:30  140  2,3
35  15.11.2021 06:00  140  2,1
37  15.11.2021 05:00  123  1,7
38  15.11.2021 04:30  115  2,2
39  15.11.2021 04:00  115    2
40  15.11.2021 03:30  123  1,7
41  15.11.2021 03:00  134  1,8
42  15.11.2021 02:30  127  2,4
43  15.11.2021 02:00  121  2,5
44  15.11.2021 01:30  131  2,3
45  15.11.2021 01:00  129  2,1
46  15.11.2021 00:30  134  2,1
47  15.11.2021 00:00  133  1,7
```

I was wondering if it is possible to use the value of a cell to find the row wherein the value belong?

I have found the value by using:

```
row_1=df.iloc[:, [2]].max().
```

I have tried, searched, and failed to find a way to make it happen.
I hope you could find time to help me out.

```
elif Nov == str(15):
    def b():
        from openpyxl import load_workbook
        wb = load_workbook(filename='Wind.xlsx', 
                         read_only=True)
        ws = wb['Sheet1']
        data_rows = []
        for row in ws['34':'81']:
            data_cols = []
            for cell in row:
                data_cols.append(cell.value)
            data_rows.append(data_cols)
        import pandas as pd
        df = pd.DataFrame(data_rows)
        row_1=df.iloc[:, [2]].max()
        print(row_1)
        print (df)
    b()
```

Comment: can this value be in any column? What value would it be, for example?

Comment: The value would be 3,4
But I would like to find the value through the variable row_1. Then I do not have to find enter the max() for each def in my code :)

Comment: Can you please include a minimum reproducible example? For example, include the output of `df.head().to_dict()` and your expected output. What do you mean by "use the value of a cell to find the row wherein the value belong"? What value are your searching for?

Comment: I would like to find a way to use the value of a certain cell (from excel) to determine the row and display the row where the value is placed.

I use openpyxl and pandas.

The max() value should stay within the variable so I would not have to withdraw the changing value from the variable

Answer (score 0):

You could for example, if this was your dataframe, df

```
   col1  col2
0   36      5
1   2       8
2   4       9
3   6       7
4   15      28
```

Do this, by selecting the column you are looking for.

```
df.col1[df.col1 == 15].index.tolist()
```

You would get `[4]`.

This of course only works by column.

You could also search column by column iteratively.

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df.col[df.col== 15].index.tolist():
        print(col, df.col[df.col== 15].index.tolist()[0])
```

The output would be `col1 4`.

You can change the formatting easily from there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I am looking for a way to use the variable row_1 to find the row which the max value belong. I have to repeat the process some times so I have to keep it as short a possible :)

Comment: yeah that can be done too, but  i need some an example of your dataframe and the output

Comment: I have posted an example of the output :)